# Best practices for sharing gatling testing base

Tags: java, scala, maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I need an advice on the code organisation and the tests sharing.

Let me start with describing the situation: we have an architecture where every separate team develops its own unique business component and their codebases don't really interfere with each other with each other. These are Node.js projects though, but the technologies behind them don't really matter.

One of the teams decided to create the gatling for load testing of its application and created a small, but very useful though project. And it worked just fine, so many other teams decided to adopt this project for their own purposes, slightly changing scenarios, but leaving the same simulation code setup etc. Not familiar with java/scala/maven etc... they just copied the whole project into the subfolder of the npm project.

Of course this makes it impossible for the centralised “core” changes and any other maintenance.

So my question is... what would be the best practice, the ideal way to organise the code in such manner, that our javascript developers ideally would only  have to create couple of scenario Scala (or maybe even something else) files in some folder in their project and then just use one or two commands so that it would automatically pull common code from private repository and run the tests.

What I'm thinking about so far:

Creating an archetype with the testing codebase and then running “archetype:generate  clean install gatling:execute” etc...

But this will do the same thing again. Creating the whole copy of the project in a subdirectory of another...

Thanks everyone!